# Why does Material-UI Select element not display label outline correctly?

Tags: material-ui

The following code is used to display a MUI (v5.2.3) Select element with a label.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl} disabled={props.disabled}>
  <InputLabel id="waiverStatus">Waiver Status</InputLabel>
  <Select
    name={props.name}
    value={props.waiverStatusID.toString()}
    labelId="waiverStatus"
    onChange={handleWaiverStatusChange}
  >
    {props.waiverStatus.map((vs: WaiverStatus) => (
      <MenuItem key={vs.waiverStatusID} value={vs.waiverStatusID}>{vs.status}</MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

However, when the select element is rendered the "outline" drawn around the element has a "strike through" effect through the label. In comparison a text field control displays the label properly.

[image]

Why does the Select element not display the outline properly like the text field?

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing label inside `Select` component. You have to use ***label*** in two places. One for `InputLabel` and another one for `Select`. Here is your fix, I just added ***label*** prop in `Select`:

```
  <FormControl className={classes.formControl} disabled={props.disabled}>

    <InputLabel id="waiverStatus">Waiver Status</InputLabel>

    <Select
      label="Waiver Status"
      name={props.name}
      value={props.waiverStatusID.toString()}
      labelId="waiverStatus"
      onChange={handleWaiverStatusChange}
    >
      {props.waiverStatus.map((vs: WaiverStatus) => (
        <MenuItem key={vs.waiverStatusID} value={vs.waiverStatusID}>
          {vs.status}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>

  </FormControl>
```